# How to configure a non-standard linker for an autotooled build?

Tags: linker, configure, autotools, libtool

I wanted to configure an autotooled project to invoke a non-standard
linker (the [`gold` linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29)),
using the stock autotools of Linux Mint 16/Ubuntu 13.10

I believed I would achieve this by:

- `libtoolize`-ing the project
- Running `./configure LD=/path/to/my/linker ... etc.`

However this has been ineffective. `libtoolize` has been successful. After
a standard `./configure; make` I now see that `libtool` is doing the
linking:

```
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2    -o helloworld helloworld.o
```

But passing `LD=/path/to/my/linker` to `configure` makes no difference. Experimentally,
I even ran:

```
./configure LD=/does/not/exist
```

expecting to provoke an error, but I didn't. The output contains:

```
checking if the linker (/does/not/exist -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the g++ linker (/does/not/exist -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
```

And thereafter a make continues to link, successfully, invoking `g++` exactly as before.

What is the right way to configure a non-standard linker?

Comment: @usr1234567, I see your bounty, but I have no reason to think that the answer already present, though old, is not still valid.  If you have specific reason to think so then you would probably be better off posing a question about that, rather than posting a bounty on this question, so that you can explain the circumstances in which the posted answer is not working for you.

Comment: @usr1234567, I'm not seeing what you consider improper or hackish about the answer provided.  If you're saying that there are better *compiler options* for specifying a linker then that's fine, but it's not really about the Autotools, and moreover, the way to apply such options should be reasonably clear from the answer already provided.  And if you think you *know* a better solution then posting it as an answer is probably going to be more effective than posting a bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But passing LD=/path/to/my/linker to configure makes no difference

This is because `LD` is almost never and should almost never be used to link any user-space program. Correct links are performed by using the appropriate *compiler driver* (`gcc`, `g++`, etc) instead.

> What is the right way to configure a non-standard linker?

If you have `/some/path/ld` and you want `gcc` to use that `ld`, pass `-B/some/path` flag to gcc.

It then follows that you likely want:

```
./configure CC='gcc -B/some/path' CXX='g++ -B/some/path' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this via a Google search, though my scenario is a bit different from yours; there was no libtool involved.  An old open source program's `Makefile` was hard-coding `ld` to create an object file with a symbol from binary data.

This is what I ended up doing to work around the lack of `$(LD)` being recognized when passed to `configure`:

https://github.com/turboencabulator/tuxnes/commit/bab2747b175ee7f2fc3d9afb28d69d82db054b5e

Basically I added to `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CHECK_TOOL([LD], [ld])
```

Leaving this answer here for if someone else lands via a google search.